# entity framework, contains and conditional operators (uses charindex insted of like)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have the following statement:

```
l.StreamName.Contains(vid == user.Username ? "live" : "")
```

When I capture the SQL on the server side this is translated into the following SQL :

```
CAST(
    CHARINDEX(
        CASE WHEN ('asdfg' = 'dfghy') 
            THEN N'live' 
            ELSE N'' 
        END,
        [Extent1].[StreamName]
    ) AS int)
) > 0
```

Witch obviously does not work since the charindex of '' is never > 0. Is this a bug in EF or is there something I don't understand. From tracing other like statements I've seen that EF translates

```
l.StreamName.Contains("")
```

Into

```
[Extent1].[StreamName] like '%%'
```

And this works.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this filtering conditionally. Do not try to generate `like '%%'` (actually it makes no sense)

```
if (vid == user.Username)
   query = query.Where(l => l.StreamName.Contains("live"));
```

Answer (score 0):

well, your should do something like that (it would be easier if you showed more code)

```
.Where(l =>vid == user.UserName ? l.StreamName.Contains("live") : true)
```